# Смена класса при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток.
Не могу решить простую задачу.
При нажатии на кнопку с одним классом, нужно поменять на active другой класс.

HTML :

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
                <button onclick="showPanel(0,'transparent')" class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>

                <div class="text">
                    <h3>+ Booking</h3>
                    <p>Some Text</p>                      
                </div>
                <div class="poly">
                    <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
                </div>
```

И сам скрипт, который не работает :

```
var polys = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonContainer .nav__link");
var act = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonContainer .poly")
polys.forEach(pls => {
  pls.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
      if (polys[i] != this)
        act[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Comment: Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку Вы переключаете у этой кнопки на `active`, а у всех `div` с классом `.poly` удаляете `active`. Объясните чего конкретно Вы хотите добиться? Чтобы при нажатии `.nav-link` у него исчезал `active`, а появлялся у `.poly` и наоборот?

Comment: Это Табы. Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку .nav__link, менялся класс .poly на .poly active. При этом классов .nav__link 4шт и столько же .poly. То есть класс .active добавляется тем кнопкам на которую нажали а у остальных он удаляется.

Comment: они расположены вместе? Имеется ввиду кнопка и `div` всегда находятся рядом, или кнопка может находиться в одном месте, а в `div` в другом?

Comment: Они расположены вместе

Comment: прикрепил картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с комментариями в коде.

```html
    <button onclick="" class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>

    <div class="text">
        <h3>+ Booking</h3>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="poly">
        <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
    </div>
    <button onclick="" class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>

        <div class="text">
            <h3>+ Booking</h3>
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="poly">
            <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
        </div>
        <button onclick="" class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>
    
        <div class="text">
            <h3>+ Booking</h3>
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="poly">
            <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
        </div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var polys = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonContainer .nav__link");
            var act = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonContainer .poly");
            for (let i = 0; i < polys.length; i++){
                polys[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    polys.forEach(pls => {
                        pls.classList.remove("active"); // Удаляем active у всех элементов
                    });
                    act.forEach(pls1 => {
                        pls1.classList.remove("active"); // Удаляем active у всех элементов
                    });
                    polys[i].classList.toggle("active"); // Переключаем класс активного элемента на active
                    act[i].classList.toggle("active"); // Переключаем класс активного элемента на active
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не вешайте обработчики событий в цикле...

```js
let prevElements = []; // Для предыдущего нажатого элемента.
document.querySelector(".buttonContainer").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let button = e.path.find(el => el.classList && el.classList.contains("nav__link") ? true : false);
  if (!button) return false;
  let poly = findElClassPoly(button.nextElementSibling, "poly"); // Ищем элемент с классом poly
  let els = [button, poly]; // Массив элементов (можно обойтись без него).
  if (button.classList.contains("active")) { // Если нажали на active элемент (второй раз).
    els.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));
    return false;
  }
  if (prevElements) { // Если есть предыдущий элемент, удаляем класс active
    prevElements.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));
    prevElements.length = 0; // Удаляем предыдущий элемент
  }
  els.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add("active");
    prevElements.push(el); // Добавляем текущий элемент.
  });
});

function findElClassPoly(elem, cl) {
  if (elem.classList.contains(cl)) return elem;
  return findElClassPoly(elem.nextElementSibling, cl);
}
```

```css
.nav__link.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.poly.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <button class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>+ Booking</h3>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="poly">
    <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
  </div>

  <button class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>+ Booking</h3>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="poly">
    <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
  </div>

  <button class="nav__link"><span><img src="./img/book.png" width="110px" height="110px"></span></button>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>+ Booking</h3>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="poly">
    <img src="./img/poly.png" alt="" style="height: 15px;">
  </div>
</div>
```